# Structure for products database: How to store a list of options for each product?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for some advice as to which direction to head in re the design of a product database and the best methods for storing / retrieving data from it. The block I'm hitting is in how to best represent the various (valid) options that a product may have.

The basic structure is (not actual table definitions):

```
PRODUCT_TABLE {
ID(int),
NAME(varchar),
AVAILABLEOPTIONS(varchar),
etc...
}

COLOROPTIONS_TABLE {
ID(int),
COLORNAME(varchare),
etc...
}

BODYOPTIONS_TABLE {
ID,
BODYNAME,
etc...
}
```

What would be the best way to store a value in the AVAILABLEOPTIONS field that would allow me to specify the OPTIONS tables and the ID's within those tables that the product is available in. (i.e. A product might not be available with all the options in a particular option table)

I've done a bunch of research (mainly on this great site) and looked at JSON, serialising values, multidimensional arrays etc, but I'm not sure the best way to go.

In the end, the AVAILABLEOPTIONS value will be used to display the options on a product page or used to construct a form for a user to generate a valid product code. I'll also be trying to setup an input form that allows an admin to generate the availableoptions value for storage in the DB.

Any tips or thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

---

I'm not sure if this is the right place to put this update, but here goes.

Have done more research and it seems the storage of multiple values in a single field is a definite no-no. I'm not sure the EAV model is right for my needs either. But when it comes to normalising the database requirements I have, I'm not sure I've got it figured out yet. I've come up with this:

Image Here: http://dev.aqualux.com.au/images/1.png
(Wouldn't let me post an image in the edit because I'm too new here...)

Where pid/oid in the orange tables are foreign keys. The issue I'm not grasping is that any given product can have multiple options of a given type, or none at all....

Thanks

Comment: Don't. Don't store a list in a single column. Do some research on `normalization`, and learn how to properly structure your tables. You can start with this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Storing a list in a single column makes it extremely difficult to use in queries (or virtually anything else like UIs). You also don't store references to tables; you `JOIN` on tables by IDs; if you have multiple options, you should have multiple rows in an intermediate table, one for each option, and join other tables on that one. Again, research. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite is absolutely right. If you store the available options as a list, that means you'll never be able to get at your data using simple database queries -- everything will be a matter of doing a query, pulling the result into PHP, and decoding your list. This means that a simple question like "which products come in blue" will end up requiring several separate queries. Maybe instead make an AVAILABLEOPTIONS table that can have many entries for a given product, with each entry representing one option (so the row's data would include a product ID, an option type, and an option ID).

Comment: Thanks Ken. There are lots of people out there looking for way's to do it like this, but I'm gathering it's not the best approach. Will keep researching!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you thought of creating an additional table to act like a bridge? Recently, I built a database to store Adobe Captivate results in MSSQL. One of the requirements was to create a unique student based off the employee and their department. This alone, was three tables where I used the bridge as my identifier for the individual assessments.

I've posted snippets from my blog below. Mind you that this is pulled directly from MSSQL.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[division](
    [id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [divisionName] [VARCHAR](50)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[employee](
    [id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [personName] [VARCHAR](50)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[student](
    [id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [employee_id] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [division_id] [INT] NOT NULL

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[core](
    [id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [assessment_id] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [status_id] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [rawScore] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [maxScore] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [minScore] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [accuracy] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [TIME] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [student_id] [INT] NOT NULL, /****** My unique record ******/
    [DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL
```

So in your case, you would have an Options table

```
CREATE TABLE options(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    color SMALLINT,
    body SMALLINT
);
```

And modify your PRODUCT table so that your AVAILABLEOPTIONS is SMALLINT and the foreign key, similarly like https://stackoverflow.com/a/1545264.

Comment: Asking people to visit your blog to read the details of your answer isn't an answer. If your blog site is down, your post here becomes meaningless, and the content isn't searchable. If you want to post a link to the off-site blog post, do it as a comment to the original question; if you want to use it as an answer, put all of the relevant information here and post the link as an additional reference for a detailed discussion of that information.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading correctly, you're making it harder than it is.

You store the products in the products table

```
PRODUCT_TABLE {
    ID(int),
    NAME(varchar),
    etc...
}
```

Then reference the Id in your options table.  I'd work out a way to have one options table though.  The following example uses the [EAV model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) that magento uses.

```
OPTIONS_TABLE {
    PRODUCT_ID(int),
    ATTRIBUTE(varchar), // colorname, or bodyname
    VALUE(varchar) // value
}
```

To get a product and its options you do a simple join

```
select
    product_table.id,...options_table.attribute, options_table.value
where
   product_table.id=<ID> and options_table.product_id = options_table.id
```

Comment: Hi Galen, Thanks for this, I think you're right I may have been making it harder than it is. Will do a small scale test now with the approach you suggest and see how it goes.