# Add new column with foreign key constraint in one command

Tags: sql

I am trying to add a new column that will be a foreign key. I have been able to add the column and the foreign key constraint using two separate `ALTER TABLE` commands:

```
ALTER TABLE one
ADD two_id integer;

ALTER TABLE one
ADD FOREIGN KEY (two_id) REFERENCES two(id);
```

Is there a way to do this with one ALTER TABLE command instead of two? I could not come up with anything that works.

Comment: In MYSQL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545253/mysql-adding-column-and-foreign-keys#answer-20758448

Answer (score 238, accepted):

As so often with SQL-related question, it depends on the DBMS.  Some DBMS allow you to combine `ALTER TABLE` operations separated by commas. For example...

**[Informix](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0290.htm)** syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE one
    ADD two_id INTEGER,
    ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(two_id) REFERENCES two(id);
```

The syntax for [IBM DB2 LUW](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000888.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F2-12-7-31) is similar, repeating the keyword ADD but (if I read the diagram correctly) not requiring a comma to separate the added items.

**Microsoft [SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)** syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE one
    ADD two_id INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(two_id) REFERENCES two(id);
```

Some others do not allow you to combine `ALTER TABLE` operations like that.  Standard SQL only allows a single operation in the `ALTER TABLE` statement, so in Standard SQL, it has to be done in two steps.

Comment: Second Add and constraint.

Comment: For the SQL part, to give name to the constraint, you write it like this:

ALTER TABLE [Messages]
    ADD [AlertTriggerID] BIGINT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FK_Messages_AlertTriggers
    FOREIGN KEY (AlertTriggerID) REFERENCES AlertTriggers (AlertTriggerID);

Comment: MySQL syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545253/how-to-add-a-column-and-make-it-a-foreign-key-in-single-mysql-statement#answer-20758448

Answer (score 108):

In MS-SQLServer:

```
ALTER TABLE one
ADD two_id integer CONSTRAINT fk FOREIGN KEY (two_id) REFERENCES two(id)
```

Comment: I don't think the question needs clarifying, as the accepted answer already states that there's a big difference between DB engines in how to do it, what needs to be clarified is your answer, so I just did that

Comment: Up for naming your constraint. The accepted answer lets the system generate the name, which is icky and hard to manage later.

Answer (score 26):

In **MS SQL SERVER:**

**With user defined foreign key name**

```
ALTER TABLE tableName
ADD columnName dataType,
CONSTRAINT fkName FOREIGN KEY(fkColumnName) 
   REFERENCES pkTableName(pkTableColumnName);
```

**Without user defined foreign key name**

```
ALTER TABLE tableName
ADD columnName dataType,
FOREIGN KEY(fkColumnName) REFERENCES pkTableName(pkTableColumnName);
```

Answer (score 19):

For SQL Server it should be something like

```
ALTER TABLE one
ADD two_id integer constraint fk foreign key references two(id)
```

Answer (score 6):

**2020 Update**

It's pretty old question but people are still returning to it I see. In case the above answers did not help you, make sure that you are using same data type for the new column as the id of the other table.

In my case, I was using Laravel and I use "unsigned integer" for all of my ids as there is no point of having negative id LOL.

So for that, the raw SQL query will change like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name`
ADD `column_name` INTEGER UNSIGNED,
ADD CONSTRAINT constrain_name FOREIGN KEY(column_name) REFERENCES foreign_table_name(id);
```

*I hope it helps*

Comment: "ADD CONSTRAINT" should just be "CONSTRAINT", yes?

Answer (score 5):

In [Oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Database) :

```
ALTER TABLE one ADD two_id INTEGER CONSTRAINT Fk_two_id REFERENCES two(id);
```

Answer (score 4):

[PostgreSQL DLL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) to add an FK column:

```
ALTER TABLE one
ADD two_id INTEGER REFERENCES two;
```

Answer (score 2):

For DB2, the syntax is:

```
ALTER TABLE one ADD two_id INTEGER FOREIGN KEY (two_id) REFERENCES two (id);
```

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server with constraint name

```
ALTER TABLE one
ADD two_id INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK_name FOREIGN KEY (two_id) REFERENCES two(id);
```

Answer (score 1):

`ALTER TABLE TableName
 ADD NewColumnName INTEGER,
 FOREIGN KEY(NewColumnName) REFERENCES [ForeignKey_TableName](Foreign_Key_Column)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below in SQL Server

```
ALTER TABLE one
ADD two_id int foreign key
REFERENCES two(id)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you also need to add default values in case you already have some rows in the table then add **DEFAULT val**

```
ALTER TABLE one
ADD two_id int DEFAULT 123,
FOREIGN KEY(two_id) REFERENCES two(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE product
ADD FOREIGN KEY (product_ID) REFERENCES product(product_ID);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, comment your answers when they are just code. In your case, there are many answers quite similar to yours, so expose the benefits of yours.

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL SERVER:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
SELECT  TOP 1 1  
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE   TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' 
AND     TABLE_NAME = 'yourTable' 
AND     COLUMN_NAME = 'yourNewColumn')
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE yourTable ADD yourNewColumn INT NOT NULL 
    CONSTRAINT DF_yourTable_yourNewColumn DEFAULT (1) 
    CONSTRAINT FK_yourTable_lookupTable FOREIGN KEY (yourNewColumn) REFERENCES LookupTable(Id)
    ON UPDATE  NO ACTION 
    ON DELETE  NO ACTION 
END
GO
```