# Error in MySQL when trying to make foreign key refer to primary key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am trying to make a foreign key in the table songs refer to the primary key in the table artists, but I get Error Code: 3780. Referencing column 'song_name' and referenced column 'artist_id' in foreign key constraint 'songs_ibfk_1' are incompatible. What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE artists(
artist_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
artist_name VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE songs(
song_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
song_name VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE charts(
song_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
song_name VARCHAR(100),
weeks_on_chart INT,
top_rank INT
);

ALTER TABLE songs ADD FOREIGN KEY (song_name) REFERENCES artists (artist_id);
```

Comment: Please add some sample data to your question.

Comment: Try this in Workbench, it has a GUI that lets you setup tables and then right click and link them up pretty easy.

Comment: OHHH I SEE THE PROBLEM NOW ...
Join on the PRIMARY KEY ... not the Varchar ...  you link primary key to primary key to make a foreign key.

Comment: No, typically you do not join a primary key of one table to the primary key of the other table. That would mean each artist could only have one song. There are some cases where a 1-to-1 relationship is appropriate, but I assume this is not one of those cases.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434518/mysql-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed-error)

Comment: Clearly this was going to be a faq. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Answer (score 2):

So, I'm double checking this, but you're not referencing the data. You're trying to make song_name a foreign key that references artist_id, but they are not only two different types, but not the data you're trying to link. Foreign keys and primary keys should reference each other and be the same type, as far as I understand. If you want to make a foreign key link the two tables together, I recommend adding another column, labeling it artist_id in the songs table and then have that reference the primary key in the artists table.

```
CREATE TABLE artists(
artist_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
artist_name VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE songs(
song_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
song_name VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE charts(
song_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
song_name VARCHAR(100),
weeks_on_chart INT,
top_rank INT
);

ALTER TABLE songs
  ADD COLUMN artist_id INT,
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (artist_id) REFERENCES artists(artist_id);
```

Referenced: [How to add a column and make it a foreign key in single MySQL statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545253/how-to-add-a-column-and-make-it-a-foreign-key-in-single-mysql-statement)

Comment: Thanks! It seems that the problem was the two different types of data. I altered table songs and added artist_id INT, which linked nicely as a foreign key to the primary key in table artists, now that thay were both INTs. Today´s lesson! :) (I also renamed song_name to the more appropriate song_title because it bugged me...)